# Django-2.2 NoReverseMatch error. Cannot redirect to next page

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-2.2

After submission of a create form in my web app it should redirect in to a single page where it displays the new product that is entered. instead of that, it shows :

`Reverse for 'category' with keyword arguments '{'pk': UUID('e3ec4273-22c9-450f-87c9-d12973dce3c1')}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['app/products/category/<int:pk>']`

> views.py

```
def create_category(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = CategoryForm(request.POST,request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.creator = request.user
            data.updater = request.user
            data.auto_id = get_auto_id(ProductCategory)
            data.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('products:category',kwargs={"pk":data.pk}))
        else:
            ...
    else:
        ...
def category(request,pk):
    instance = get_object_or_404(ProductCategory.objects.filter(pk=pk))
    context = {
        'title': "Category : " + instance.name,
        'instance' : instance,
    }
    return render(request,'products/category.html',context)
```

> urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


app_name = 'products'

urlpatterns = [
    path('categories',views.categories,name='categories'),
    path('category/create',views.create_category,name='create_category'),
    path('category/<int:pk>',views.category,name='category'),
    path('category/edit/<int:pk>',views.edit_category,name='edit_category'),
    path('category/delete/<int:pk>',views.delete_category,name='delete_category'),
]
```

Th thing is the form is submitted and the values are added to database. But it doesn't move to the next step.

*I am new to django 2 so not very sure on how to pass pk in urls/path*

Comment: can your try changing your url to this: `path('category/<uuid:pk>',views.category,name='category'),`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your url:

```
path('category/<int:pk>',views.category,name='category'),
               ^^^^
```

You are expecting an **integer** but in code you are passing an **UUID**. So change the url to:

```
path('category/<uuid:pk>',views.category,name='category'),
```

More information can be found in [**`documentation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#path-converters).